# Плавное перемещение ползунка у видео

Tags: javascript

Если продолжительность видео скажем секунд 5-10, то ползунок перемещается шагами, нету в нем плавности.

Пробовал

```
transition: 30ms height ease-in-out;
```

То получается, что ползунок под конец не успевает. Как я понял через css не выход, поскольку продолжительность не большая и в ширину ползунок может быть как больше так и меньше.

Быть может у кого есть готовое решение, так чтобы учитывать продолжительность видео и ширину ползунка. Подстраивать анимацию под данные параметры через js?

**Пример**

```js
        let interval = 10, // 10 процентов, может 20 а может и 50.
            last     = 0; 
        setInterval(_ => {
            pr.style.width = (last = (interval + last)) + '%';
        }, 1000);
```

```css
        #pr {
            height: 5px;
            background: red;
            position: fixed;
            bottom:0;
            left:0;
            width: 0;
        }
```

```html
<div id='pr'></div>
```

Собственно пример, может быть шаг в 5% от ширины блока, может быть 50%. Все зависит от продолжительности видео. Ширина блока в процентах.

На сколько я понимаю, через css реализовать плавную анимацию невозможно. Иначе ползунок будет не успевать или наоборот, так как продолжительность видео разная..

Comment: А почему для ползунка видео выбрано св-во `height`?

Comment: Перепутал, просто css свойство вытащил с другого элемента.

Comment: Хорошо, приложите пожалуйста к вопросу ваш минимальный воспроизводимый код (нажав на CTRL+M в редакторе вопроса). Вставьте необходимые HTML, CSS и JS код

Comment: Дополнил примреом

Comment: если у тебя шаг ползунка большой - всегда будет выглядеть как рывок.

Comment: зачем вообще интервал если у видео есть событие [timeupdate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/timeupdate_event)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для правильного рассчёта и плавного перемещения ползунка у видео необходимо использовать такие свойства элемента видео:

**video.currentTime** - текущая временная позиция во время воспроизведения;

**video.duration** - подолжительность видеофайла.

**setInterval()** с частотой повторения **одна секунда** не подходит для плавного движения ползунка при воспроизведении коротких видеофайлов.

Есть три способа плавного воспроизведения:

**1** - использование свойства **video.ontimeupdate**:

```
video.ontimeupdate = () => { 
  polzunok.style.width = video.currentTime / video.duration *
    progressWidth + "px";
}
```

Это срабатывает 4 раза в секунду, что даёт не очень высокую плавность.

**2** - использование **setInterval()** с периодом в пределах 20 - 100 милисекунд:

```
setInterval(_ => {
    polzunok.style.width = 
      video.currentTime / video.duration * progressWidth + "px";
}, 20);
```

**3** - использование **requestAnimationFrame()**:

```
const step = () => {
  polzunok.style.width = video.currentTime / video.duration *
    progressWidth + "px";
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

Плавными являются **второй** и **третий** варианты.

Следующий код является дополняющим до полного кода примера, в который нужно будет вставить предварительно выбранный вами вариант обеспечения плавности проигрывания:

```js
video.ontimeupdate = () => {
    polzunok.style.width = video.currentTime / video.duration * progressWidth + "px";
}

setInterval(_ => {
    polzunok.style.width = video.currentTime / video.duration * progressWidth + "px";
}, 20);

const step = () => {
    polzunok.style.width = video.currentTime / video.duration * progressWidth + "px";
    requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
requestAnimationFrame(step);
```

```html
<style>
#contauner{
    border-style: solid;
}
#polzunok{
    width: 0px;
    height: 15px;
    background: red;
}
</style>
<video id=video src="https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ForBiggerEscapes.mp4" controls width="300"></video><br /><br />
<div id=contauner><div id=polzunok></div></div>
<script>
let progressWidth = 300; // ширина прогрессбара
contauner.style.width = progressWidth + "px";
 // сюда вставляем код выбранного способа
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Можете попробовать так:

```js
const videoLengthinSec = 10;
const speed = 1000;
let currentSec = 0;
let timeout = null;

const setProgress = () => {
  let currentLength = (currentSec++ / videoLengthinSec) * 100;
  
  if (currentLength > 100) {
    currentLength = 100;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }
  
  pr.style.width = `${currentLength}%`;
  
  timeout = setTimeout(setProgress, speed);
}

timeout = setTimeout(setProgress, speed);
```

```css
#pr {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  transition: 1s width linear;
}
```

```html
<div id='pr'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение основано на частоте удлинения прогресс бара, и она обратно пропорциональна длине видео (чем длиннее видео тем реже длина увеличивается)

В формуле `1000/ (100/n)`:

- `n` - это количество секунд
- 100 - это `100%` (для обратной пропорциональности)
- `1000` - одна секунда и соответственно время видео должно быть в секундах (поэтому если видео 3 минуты нужно передать 180 в качестве n)

```js
function timer(n, id){
    let max = n
    setInterval(_ => {
      id.innerText = `${max - n--} sec` 
      if (n === 0){
         n = max
      }
    }, 1000);

}

function inc(n, id){
  let last = 0; 
    setInterval(_ => {
      id.style.width = (last += 1) + '%';
      if (last === 100){
         id.style.width = '0px'
         last = 0
      }
    }, 1000/ (100/n));
}

inc(10, pr)
timer(10,pr)

inc(20, pr2)
timer(20,pr2)

inc(50, pr3)
timer(50,pr3)
```

```css
#pr {
  height: 5px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:160px;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
}

#pr2 {
  height: 5px;
  background: orange;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:130px;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
}

#pr3 {
  height: 5px;
  background: green;
  position: fixed;
  bottom:100px;
  left:0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='pr'>0 sec</div>
<div id='pr2'>0 sec</div>
<div id='pr3'>0 sec</div>
```

Comment: 1000/n -  как тут привязать, есть только есть продолжительность видео. Если продолжительность меньше, то интервал был тоже меньше, то есть обновлялся чаще и наоборот. Если тайм больше, то частота(интервал) был больше.

Comment: я поправил пример, отображаю теперь секунды - зеленое 50, красное 10 и оранжевое 20 (числа скачут из-за ширины, ну и они не нужны как я понял, чисто для примера)